# SCHTASK from bat file - access denied

Tags: cmd.exe, scheduled-tasks

I have created a bat file that creates schedule task -

the .bat file is written as such:

> schtasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN DailyOpfxFileRemover /TR "%cd%/opfx_remover.bat" /ST 01:00:00

Running the .bat file results in access denied .

running the command directly in CMD succeeds .

Tried running as admin , checked if admin group lacks permissions

How do I make the .bat file work?

Answer (score 0):

It's your use of `%cd%` - I recommend changing `%cd%` to the set path where `opfx_remover.bat` is located.

When you run it from command, the `%cd%` is `%USERPROFILE%` (the user).
When you run it from command as admin, the `%cd%` is `%WINDIR%\System32` (cmd.exe location).
When you run it from batch, the `%cd%` is `%cd%` (current directory; where you run batch from).
When you run it from batch, the `%cd%` is `%WINDIR%\System32` (cmd.exe location).

For more info on `schtask` I recommend [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490996(v=technet.10)).
For more info on `cd` I recommend [here](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html).

---

Also, you have a forward slash `/` in your path (`"%cd%/opfx_remover.bat"`) instead of the `\` you likely need. It didn't cause issues running the `schtasks` making batch file but it could cause issues within `schtasks`. Otherwise I've been unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: The .bat file that creates the scheduled task and the opfx_remover.bat are located in same directory .
manually writing the path still results in access denied

Comment: When you run it directly from `cmd.exe`, is it as admin or through your user profile? Is there an error code with your Access Denied message? I still recommend setting the path instead of using a variable there. On a side note, I've always had much better luck creating the task, exporting it to an .xml file, then importing it when I needed to batch install a scheduled task on multiple different machines - usually just requires deleting some of the values from the .xml that will hang it.

Comment: Hey , 
When running both with explicit directory and with variable the .bat returns access denied with no error code, 

typing the command into the CMD (Administrator) works fine , 
running bat file as administrator results in access denined

typing the command into cmd